# RequireJS on Amazon S3 uses wrong URL

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, requirejs

I have a script tag like this:

```
<script src="https://ZZZ.s3.amazonaws.com/js/require-jquery.js?Signature=XXX&amp;Expires=1369597850&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=YYY" data-main="https://ZZZ.s3.amazonaws.com/js/snippet_create.js?Signature=XXX&amp;Expires=1369597850&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=YYY"></script>
```

But the asset is failing to load, and it looks like it's overwriting the resource path with my local page:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) http://localhost:8000/snippet_create.js?Signature=XXX&Expires=1369597850&AWSAccessKeyId=YYY
```

This is all sitting in django-require, but it's happening client-side so I'm not sure I know why.

My build file looks like this (pretty boilerplate):

```
/**
 * Build profile for django-require.
 * 
 * This supports all the normal configuration available to a r.js build profile. The only gotchas are:
 *
 *   - 'baseUrl' will be overidden by django-require during the build process.
 *   - 'appDir' will be overidden by django-require during the build process.
 *   - 'dir' will be overidden by django-require during the build process. 
 */
({

    baseUrl: 'https://ZZZ.s3.amazonaws.com/js'
    /*
     * paths to use for modules
     */
    paths: {
        "util"      : "util",
        "jquery"    : "require-jquery",
        "ace"       : "ace",
        "bootstrap" : "bootstrap.min"
    },

    /**
     * shim in modules that do not follow amd specs
     */
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
          deps: ["jquery"],
          exports: "$.fn.popover"
    }
    /*
     * List the modules that will be optimized. All their immediate and deep
     * dependencies will be included in the module's file when the build is
     * done. A minimum module entry is {name: "module_name"}.
     */
    modules:  [{
            name: "snippet_create",
            exclude: ["jquery"]
    }],

    /*
     * Allow CSS optimizations. Allowed values:
     * - "standard": @import inlining, comment removal and line returns.
     * Removing line returns may have problems in IE, depending on the type
     * of CSS.
     * - "standard.keepLines": Like "standard" but keeps line returns.
     * - "none": Skip CSS optimizations.
     * - "standard.keepComments": Keeps the file comments, but removes line returns.
     * - "standard.keepComments.keepLines": Keeps the file comments and line returns.
     */
    optimizeCss: "standard",

    /*
     * How to optimize all the JS files in the build output directory.
     * Right now only the following values are supported:
     * - "uglify": Uses UglifyJS to minify the code.
     * - "uglify2": Uses UglifyJS2.
     * - "closure": Uses Google's Closure Compiler in simple optimization
     * mode to minify the code. Only available if REQUIRE_ENVIRONMENT is "rhino" (the default).
     * - "none": No minification will be done.
     */
    optimize: "uglify2",

    /*
     * By default, comments that have a license in them are preserved in the
     * output. However, for a larger built files there could be a lot of
     * comment files that may be better served by having a smaller comment
     * at the top of the file that points to the list of all the licenses.
     * This option will turn off the auto-preservation, but you will need
     * work out how best to surface the license information.
     */
    preserveLicenseComments: true,

    /*
     * The default behaviour is to optimize the build layers (the "modules"
     * section of the config) and any other JS file in the directory. However, if
     * the non-build layer JS files will not be loaded after a build, you can
     * skip the optimization of those files, to speed up builds. Set this value
     * to true if you want to skip optimizing those other non-build layer JS
     * files.
     */
    skipDirOptimize: false



})
```

I don't understand why requirejs is using the wrong url, when it's being fed a different one explicitly.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`baseUrl` must be relative. Because build need process is trying to access files on a disc and will not download them over HTTP. You can reference modules using absolute URL, but they will not be included with output.

Also, when using data main attribute you can not use query string parameters. To understand what is going on check Network panel in chrome developer tools, you will see what resources are being requested, that will help you to understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks!  I figured the baseURL wasn't the issue (since I hadn't run the build script yet), but the thing about query string params threw me.